# django filter by nested foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

Souupose I have two models like below:

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', bland=True, null=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType)
```

Now I have ProductType hierarchy like this:

```
Electronics->MobilePhone->Samsung->[galaxy, s10, s8]
Electronics->MobilePhone->Apple->[Iphone, Ipad, Ipod]
```

For sure, MobilePhone is under Electronics and Apple is under MobilePhone ProductType and finally  [galaxy, s10, s8] are Products of Samsung ProductType. 
Now how can I filter on Product model to get all the Products where **ProductType=MobilePhone** ?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Nice reply. May be you want to change Product.objects.get(product_type__name='MobilePhone') to Product.objects.get(product_type__name='MobilePhones') as cjahangir's request was such. (at)cjahangir a ForiegnKey in Django requires that you also give an on_delete argument. It is one of two required arguments. See here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)  May be you want to add that.

Comment: @Amit, I just wrote a pseudo code here . But alas, what Willem Van Onsem said is not working for me.

Comment: What is the error or result?

Comment: Dear @Amit, it returns me empty queryset. But if I query with 'Samsung', it is working. But not for 'MobilePhone' or even 'Electronics'

Comment: What is the output of ProductType.objects.filter(name__iexact="MobilePhone").count() and ProductType.objects.filter(name__iexact="Electronics").count()? If it is non-zero then the entries exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django 2 you should add on_delete ( models.CASCADE, models.PROTECTED, models.SET_NULL) 
What I usually do just to make it as much error  free is:

```
prods = Product.objects.filter(product_type__name__iexact="MobilePhone")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to write a raw query to get the last limit of the chain. 
If it's an infinity chain, then you will need to check the next result using a loop. I just hope you will get a better answer from better developers and I will be able to learn it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to your Product model that returns **a list of all the ProductType objects that it is a part of**. Like so:

```py
class Product(model.Model):
    name = ...
    product_type = ...

    @property
    def product_types_list(self):
        product_types = []
        obj = self  # reference object
        while obj.product_type is not None:
            product_types.append(obj.product_type)
            obj = obj.product_type
        # Reverse the list to get the proper hierarchy
        product_types.reverse()
        return product_types
```

After that, you can filter the products like so:

```py
mobile_phone_type = ProductType.objects.get(name='MobilePhone')

mobile_phones = []  # list of filtered mobile phones

for product in Product.objects.all():
    if mobile_phone_type in product.product_types_list:
        mobile_phones.append(product)
```

Your required items will then be stored in the `mobile_phones` list.